# Dataset containing spatial and temporal features (built on a CNN model)

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, cnn, prediction, matrix

A dataset contains spatial and temporal features.

It contains the time series data (2 min intervals) of the sections of a map.

It is 320*480 (320 map sections and 480-time intervals). Each row belongs to a section and each column is a time interval. So each cell in the dataset is a value of data in a map section in a time interval.

I would like to make a model to import all map sections in 40 min and predict the following 10 next min of all map sections.

So the input shape equals 320*20 and the output shape will be 320*5.

I split data to 320*20 as X and 320*5 as Y samples.

The input and the output of the model are 2-dimensional matrixes.

I can consider the input as a one channel image (320*20*1) and it is possible to use a CNN model.

The codes of the final architecture of my model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(320,20,1), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1600))

model.summary()
```

The Loss value(MSE) is about 70. 
Is it lower than the random prediction?

I reshaped the output to 1600 (320*5) which the final Dense layer expects , while the output is 2d. Does it make the model more prone to error ?